# merging two data objects

Tags: iphone

I have to merge two data objects and later separate them.Can anybody suggest me the way to go about it.It's urgent!!!!!!
please respond fast....
Thanks

Comment: way too little info....what are the objects?  class instances?  core-data objects?  What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: No one can help you because there is no such thing as a "data object". You're going to have to provide way more detail if you want an answer. What class/type are these "data objects"? What do you mean by "merge" and "seperate"? Remember, we're not standing over your shoulder looking at your code.

Comment: sorry for little information.
when i say data object,i mean NSData object and by merging i mean
"can i get one NSData object containing two NSData object,which i can retrieve later and use it as i wish.hope this will help in understanding scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [NSMutableData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html).  Specifically, look at the appendData: and appendBytes:Length methods.

You can 'merge' two NSData objects by appending them to an empty NSMutableData object.  You can then probably retrieve the data using getBytes:range: and reconstruct your NSData object with dataWithBytes:Length:.

Have a look at this article for [working with mutable binary data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002150) (includes sample code).